# Facebook Scores API not publishing open graph stories

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am a little new to the facebook SDK so please bear with me on this. I have been searching for hours and have not been able to find anything relating to my problem.

I have implemented the facebook sdk for iOS and am in the process of adding scores.

User authentication is working fine, achievements are working fine, and it appears to submit the scores fine as well with the following response:

```
{
    "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true;
}
```

and there are no errors returned. This is a native app and while it appears to be posting fine, no stories are showing up. Any idea why this would be? I want to make sure that it is working correctly prior to submitting the new version of my game.

Comment: Check your activity log on the Facebook profile the story was posted to

Comment: @Brandon Could you feed back whether my answer was is relation with the problem/solution? Could you accept it for the sake of next generation...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm getting a successful submission, but nothing appears in my activity log. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The aim of the Graph API to make stories and just sending a score is not a story.

The scores will show up if the user passes the user's friend (passing story) or made a high score (high score story).

You can check the score feed in the users's Activity Log.

WARNING! It seems that FB filter the high score story frequency, but the mechanism and timing is not public, so testing it too frequently could cause missing stories.